# NSString drawAtPoint: withAttributes: gap

Tags: cocoa, text, fonts

See the following code and two pictures:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

NSMutableDictionary* dicAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dicAttributes setObject:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Tahoma" size:18] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[dicAttributes setObject:[NSColor redColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

NSString* text = @"111111";
NSSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:dicAttributes];
[[NSColor grayColor] set];
NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
[text drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0, 0) withAttributes:dicAttributes];
NSLog(@"---------size(%f, %f)", size.width, size.height);

text = @"111\n111";
size = [text sizeWithAttributes:dicAttributes];
[[NSColor grayColor] set];
NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(100, 0, size.width, size.height));
[text drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(100, 0) withAttributes:dicAttributes];
NSLog(@"---------size(%f, %f)", size.width, size.height);
}

- (BOOL)isFlipped{
return YES;
}
```

1. This is the original screenshot.

   [image]
2. This is the screenshot I modified and I need the height of the green and yellow portions of the picture.

   [image]

Comment: Leading and descender of the font?

Comment: @Willeke No, absolutely not.